# How to make a user input sentence into all capital letters in C?

Tags: c

I need to take a user inputted sentence and make it all capital letters. However, I can not use strings yet so I was thinking that I need to use the toupper function to make it work.

However, when I run the code below it didn't print anything in capital / uppercase. I was also thinking that I might not use scanf but like a getchar instead but I'm not sure.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
      int main ()
    {
         char sen;

         printf("Enter sentence");
         scanf("%c", &sen);

         putchar (toupper(sen));

        printf("The caps are:%c\n", sen);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. But I immediately notice a huge problem. How would a sentence fit into a variable of type `char`, which holds a single character? Also, what's the purpose of the call to `putchar`?

Comment: well the question is is how to to write the code for this because i am very lost. would i put it as a int variable or what would i put?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, (no strings involved ! ):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
  int main ()
  {
     char c,u;

     printf("Enter sentence, press [enter] key to end");
     while(c=getchar()!='\n')
       {
       u=toupper(c);
       putchar (u);
       }  
 return 0;
 }
```

This converts characters, one at a time, to uppercase, and prints them, again one at a time, until the enter/return key is hit, which will make the program quit.

Comment: `char c` should be `int c`

Comment: `c=getchar()!='\n'` should be  `(c=getchar())!='\n'`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
        char str[100]="",i;
        printf("Enter a sentence\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]",str);

        for(i=0;str[i];i++)
        {
                printf("%d\t%c\n",str[i],str[i]);
                if( (str[i]>=97) && (str[i]<=122) )
                        str[i]-=32;
        }
        printf("Caps sentence is %s\n",str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do:

1) You need a `char` array to store the sentence `char sen[80];`
2) Change `scanf("%c", &sen);` to `scanf("%s", sen);` since you're not inserting a single character.
3) Use a loop to change every `char` in the array to upper case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
    sen[i] = toupper(sen[i]);
}
```

4) Change: `printf("The caps are:%c\n", sen);` to `printf("The caps are: %s\n", sen);`

```
int main ()
{
    char sen[80];

    printf("Enter sentence: ");
    scanf("%s", sen);

    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        sen[i] = toupper(sen[i]);
    }

    printf("The caps are: %s\n", sen);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a char array,say it letter to store the sentence typed by user.
Here first for loop is to read in the sentence char by char using getchar function,and then putchar function is used to print character in uppercase.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define EOL '\n'//EOL stands for end of line character.
int main()
{
  char letter[80];
  int tag,count;

  for(count=0;(letter[count]=getchar())!=EOL;++count)            
    tag=count;

   for(count=0;count<=tag;++count)
   putchar(toupper(letter[count]));

   return 0;
}
```